# Current week in Caldroid calendar

Tags: android, caldroid

I am working with Caldroid for my project. By default, I have to display the current week in the `gridView`. When a user swipe to the right, it will display the next week, and when a user swipe to the left, it will display the previous week. How can I achieve this in Caldroid?

Comment: Have you done any code yet?

Answer (score 0):

Caldroid does not support any method to show a week only. You have the following options

- Make your own calendar control
- Extend Caldroid to do so by modifying source code
- Use some other library such as [RadCalendarView](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/android/controls/calendar/calendar-overview) if it suits your need.